# Publicly available Postman collection with query parameter for locales

Tags: json, api, postman, mockserver

I need some advice about how to create publicly available Postman collection with query parameter. The data would be fix, something like:

```
{
  "home": {
    "title": "Hello"
  }
}
```

and the url would be created by Postman, e.g. https://api.postman.com/translations/titles/en

If I use https://api.postman.com/translations/titles/fr the data would be:

```
{
  "home": {
    "title": "Bonjour"
  }
}
```

Is it possible somehow? If not with Postman, what free service do you suggest?

Comment: *The data would be fix* is request body parameter or the response body?

Comment: Data can be fix, just the result needs to be different based on the query.

Comment: Okay, best and ideal way is to handle it from server side localisation. Based on language query string, server will covert response string into specified language.